# Progressive web app using Service Worker: How to cache only static (non database dependent) parts of a page?

Tags: browser-cache, indexeddb, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I have a web app (PHP/Laravel) that needs to work offline. The app is used to manage a number of people I'll call *clients*. My question concerns a page consisting of not much more than a table listing all our clients. Path is `/clients`.

Synchronization between MySQL (on server) and Indexed DB (for offline use) is working well, now I have to cache the static HTML of that page. My current approach caches the whole page *including client data from the server*. However, I don't want any data from MySQL in the cache, because when I'm offline, I get all the data from Indexed DB.

This is my simplified `offline-worker.js`:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'app-cache';

var urlsToCache = [
  '/clients'
];

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/offline-worker.js');
}

self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(evt) {
  evt.respondWith(
    caches.match(evt.request)
      .then(function(response) {

        if (response)
          return response;

        var fetchRequest = evt.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {
            if (!response || response.status != 200 || response.type != 'basic')
              return response;

            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(evt.request, responseToCache);
              });
            return response;
          }
        );
      })
  )
});
```

Right now, I'd remove the data as soon as the browser detects it's offline, but I'd rather cache a 'clean' version/template of that page from the beginning. This is a totally simplified version of `/clients`:

```
<h1>Our clients</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Charles</td>
    <td>Chaplin</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Imagine many more rows of server generated data here. 
       I'd like to get rid of all rows before caching. -->
</table>
```

What's the best way to cache `/clients` without any data from MySQL? I'm aware of the fact that the browser can't see what page elements come from a server database and which ones are static.

If I have to manually set up an offline version, that's fine. I just need to know how to tell the browser to use the offline version when there's no internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a new url route /clientsTemplate where you return only the template. This template is stored in the app cache.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'app-cache';

var urlsToCache = [
  '/clientsTemplate'
];

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/offline-worker.js');
}

self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  )
});
```

Then you can implement the fetch as follow:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
        //the url concatenate is a bit hacky, works only if you don't have any url params
        return response || caches.match(event.request.url+"Template");
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The concatenation part is a simple solution if there's a 'template' version of every page in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Stefs answer shows a simple solution if there's an offline mode version of every page in the app. By now, I've rewritten the listener for the fetch event. This is probably the simplest way to cache only a limited number of offline mode pages. Right now, theres only one such page, `/clients`. The 'standard' version of some other pages and assets is also cached.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'app-cache';

var urlsToCache = [
  '/offline/clients',
  '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
  'js/bootstrap.min.js',
  '/'
];

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/offline-worker.js');
}

// Open cache and add URLs to be cached
self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  )
});

// Define responses
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var request = event.request;

  event.respondWith(
    // Try to get page from server
    fetch(request).catch(function(error) {
      // Request failed: Get page from cache
      return caches.open('app-cache').then(function(cache) {
        // There's an offline mode version for this page
        if (request.url.indexOf('myapp.test/clients') > -1) {
          return cache.match('offline/clients');
        }
        // Standard version is used even in offline mode
        else {
          return cache.match(request.url);
        }
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would render dynamic parts (components) via JS. Each JS part would receive data it needs via Ajax. Then usual HTML and JS can be cached for later offline use. Once a user is offline, the service worker can start returning data from IndexedDB instead of the backend. The cached HTML and JS will be served by the service worker as well.